# Apply style conditionally on a React component with json-style definitions

Tags: reactjs

I have a component where style is applied in form of json and I need to override styles conditionally.

See style definitions:

```
const classes = {
  txt: {
    color: 'green',
    ...
  },
  txtBlue:{
    color: 'blue',
    ..
  },
};
```

See template:

```
<div style={classes.txt + (this.state.goBlue ? classes.txtBlue)}></div>
```

The `+ (this.state.goBlue ? classes.txtBlue)` I have written above is not working and it is just to show what I need to understand and make work.

When `this.state.goBlue` is true, I want both `classes.txt` and `classes.txtBlue` to apply to the `div`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't use the ternary operator correctly, you can do something like this:

```
<div style={ this.state.goBlue ? { ...classes.txt, ...classes.txtBlue } : classes.txt }></div>
```

This will apply both styles if `this.state.goBlue` is truthy, otherwise it will only apply `classes.txt`.

Comment: This also works and it is a better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

By adding this to the `render()` function:

```
const txtStyle =
            this.state.goBlue ?
                Object.assign({}, classes.txt, classes.txtBlue) :
                Object.assign({}, classes.txt);
```

And this to the template:

```
<div style={txtStyle}></div>
```

I was able to achieve what I wanted.